# Multiple payload on NGRX action/effect

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I need to send a put request to the API with `ngrx/effect` but the request requires id and content so MongoDB could be able to find a post.

Here is the code, I tried to set two action payloads:

```js
export class UpdatePost implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_POST

    constructor(public payload: string & Post ) { }
}
```

Here is the effect:

```js
@Effect() 
    editPost$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(PostActions.UPDATE_POST)
    .map((action: PostActions.UpdatePost) => action.payload)
    .switchMap((?) => {
        return this.postService.editPost(id, post);
    })
    .map(editedpost => ({type: PostActions.UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS, payload: editedpost}))
}
```

`editPost()` requires two parameters: id and content.

I guess my action payload should be set the other way, I'm new to `ngrx` so every advice is welcome.

Comment: you could define a payload made of 2 properties, or a constructor method that takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a variable with type string & Post, it means that this variable owns all method of Post and all method of string. That is probably not what you want.
You want that your action has a identifier (of type string) and a post. You can declare a interface for that, or your action can have several properties, as :

```
export class UpdatePost implements Action {
  readonly type = UPDATE_POST

  constructor(public id: string, public payload: Post ) { }
}
```

So then in your effect your can write :

```
@Effect() 
    editPost$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(PostActions.UPDATE_POST)
    .switchMap(action => {
        return this.postService.editPost(action.id, action.post);
    })
    .map(editedpost => ({type: PostActions.UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS, payload: editedpost}))
}
```

Comment: If you are updating a Post that means it already had been created, and so the id should be in the Post instance payload. I don't think you need two parameters.

Comment: @PierreMallet I agree with you, but it seems that id is not present in Post object of merko. May be a bad design, but I answered to its question.